# Cross platform package with bundled dependencies

Tags: python, pip, bundler, egg, python-wheel

I need an easy way to distribute a Python project with all its **dependencies included**. I *don't* want something like PyInstaller: I need to distribute *the same* cross-platform package for each user. Recompiling on each OS is not an option.

When copied and installed into another system, **the dependencies should be picked up from within the package** (and not, e.g., from the Internet). Ideally, they should be installed into an isolated environment relative to that package.

Is it possible?

### For those who know Ruby:

In Ruby, with Bundler, running `bundle package --all-platforms` will copy all my dependencies to `./vendor/cache/` within the project folder.

Then, on another machine, I can run `bundle install --deployment` and it will install the dependencies from `./vendor/cache` to the local `./vendor/bundle` path.

I'm looking for a similar procedure, with Python.